# Parsing two bytes from array to a uint16_t?

Tags: c++

I have an array of bytes, which have come from the network (and therefore big endian) and I would like to extract two of these bytes, to pass to __builtin_bswap16() and convert to little-endian.

How do I obtain the two bytes if I know the offset they are located within the array?

Comment: `atoi` and `atoll` converts a string representation of the number to a `int` or `long long` respectively.  Is your 2 byte integer represented as a string representation or a `uint16_t` in a byte array?

Comment: Please clarify your question with a minimum of code.

Comment: Also clarify what you mean by _parsing_. The normal definition doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I have re-written to question to be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract an `uint16_t` from an array of `uint8_t` without fear of alignment or aliasing issues and without re-implementing what's already provided to you by the system, use `memcpy`.

```
uint16_t val;
memcpy(&val, ptr, sizeof val);
```

If it's in network (big endian) order and you want to convert it to host order (possibly little endian but not limited to that), use `ntohs` as answered by Sam Varshavchik.

```
val = ntohs(val);
```

You *can* do it by shifting bytes, but if standard library functions already do what you want, then I'd say stick with the standard library functions<sup>*</sup> at least until you have a compelling reason not to.

<sub>* POSIX standard in this case, not C++ standard.</sub>

Comment: at last. someone mentioned memcpy - the only truly portable way.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [ntohs(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/byteorder.3.html).

Comment: That's the same as __builtin_bswap(). However, I am trying to extract the two bytes to pass to this.

Comment: You mean "unsigned char \*ptr= /* something */; uint16_t v= ((uint16_t)v[0] << 8) | v[1]"?

Comment: I think so, is there no function which wraps this? I weren't sure if reinterpet_cast would work?

Comment: reinterpret_cast will likely work also, but this will not be portable. A particular runtime implementatin might have different alignment restrictions on plain char data, then on larger types.

Comment: @mezamorphic "That's the same as __builtin_bswap()." -- No, it's not. __builtin_bswap() is not portable to other compilers, inappropriate on other platforms (big endian platforms in particular), and even if you care absolutely nothing at all about portability, it's less readable: ntohs already indicates directly that you're dealing with network byte order and want to convert to host byte order.

Answer (score 0):

Case A:

```
 value = ((uint16_t)(array[X]) << 8) | (uint16_t)array[X + 1];
```

Case B:

```
 value = ntohs(*(unit16_t*)(char*)(array + X));
```

If the type of array is already char the char * cast isn't necessary. Most of the time the compiler will figure it out anyway; but technically it's undefined behavior without it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a gcc intrinsic which wraps this? I'd be surprised if not.

Comment: Probably not but I don't track gcc intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your source data is a `uint8_t*`, since it's not specified otherwise. Therefore:

```
uint8_t *src = /* your source */;
```

You want to extract one `uint16_t` at a given offset; this means:

```
uint8_t high = src[offset], low = src[offset + 1];
uint16_t v = high << 8 | low;

/* offset and offset+1 must be in a valid range */
```

Or, more compactly:

```
uint16_t v = (src[offset] << 8) | src[offset+1];
```

Then convert `v` to little endian accordingly, but notice plain `bswap` is not enough. This is because `__builtin_bswapX` (where X is the number of bytes) simply swaps bytes, which is *not* equivalent to `htonX`/`ntohX`: these also check your machine's endianness and, if needed, go ahead and swap; otherwise they're a no-op.
Indeed, if you're on a BE architecture the `htonX` has to be a no-op (data is already BE) and vice-versa.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on why bswap isn't enough?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant bswap16()

Comment: If you're on a BE, bswap will make it LE.